# Android Studio 3.6 not able to click on text to change its ID and text

Tags: android, textfield, android-studio-3.6

I am not able to change text of text fields by double click on text. When I click on text, nothing happened. I expected a popup should be shown to change name and id.

Comment: You can change it using xml window using `android:text` attribute or design window (attributes pane) do you have problems in both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change them easily.
Please check the below screenshot.
[image: How to change id and text of textfield]

Hoping it will be helped with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the attributes pane on the right hand side. Choose your textField and its attributes will open up. Simply change the **`text`** property.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt help